# Create array from dict

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have some words in a dictionary and according to these and some sentences I want to create a specific array.

```
words = {'a': array([ 1.78505888, -0.40040435, -0.2555062 ]), 'c': array([ 0.58101204, -0.23254054, -0.5700197 ]), 'b': array([ 1.17213122,  0.38232652, -0.78477569]), 'd': array([-0.07545012, -0.10094538, -0.98136142])}

sentences = [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'd'], ['d', 'c']]
```

What I want is to get an array with the first row being the the values of 'a' and 'c' stacked vertically.
The second row being the values of 'b' and 'a' stacked vertically.
And the third, the values of 'd' and 'c' stacked vertically.

I tried this:

```
np.vstack((words[word] for word in sentences[0]))
>>> array([[ 1.78505888, -0.40040435, -0.2555062 ],
   [ 0.58101204, -0.23254054, -0.5700197 ]])
```

So this is my first row, but I'm not able to do this for 'sentences' using list comprehension (only for one).

**EDIT** : 
Basically what I'm trying to do is the following

```
first_row = np.vstack((words[word] for word in sentences[0]))
second_row = np.vstack((words[word] for word in sentences[1]))
third_row = np.vstack((words[word] for word in sentences[2]))

l = []
l.append(first_row)
l.append(second_row)
l.append(third_row)

print np.array(l)
>>> [[[ 1.78505888 -0.40040435 -0.2555062 ]
      [ 0.58101204 -0.23254054 -0.5700197 ]]

     [[ 1.17213122  0.38232652 -0.78477569]
      [ 1.78505888 -0.40040435 -0.2555062 ]
      [-0.07545012, -0.10094538, -0.98136142]]

     [[-0.07545012 -0.10094538 -0.98136142]
      [ 0.58101204 -0.23254054 -0.5700197 ]]]
```

Comment: can you please post an sample output?

Comment: Do you always have the same number of elements for each key in `words`, like its in `3's` in here? Do you always have the same number of elements per index in `sentences`, like they are in pairs in the sample data?

Comment: In the 'words' dictionary all values have the same dimension (numpy array of size n) but in 'sentences' rows can be of different length.

Comment: I think because of the "different length" criteria, you might have different number of rows in `first_row`, `second_row`, etc..  I don't think you would be able to store all those "rows" in a regular ndarray. Are you okay with having all in a list of those "rows" in the final output. Thus, it would be a list of 2D arrays, where the 2D arrays have different number of rows.

Comment: I think it would be better to have a sample `sentences` with one element being of different length like `3`. So, as an example, the first one could be `['a', 'c', 'b']` instead of `['a', 'c']`.

Comment: I changed the example, with my current solution it works with an array but I'm looking for a more pythonic way to solve my problem.

Comment: So, would you be okay with a list of 2D arrays as output?

Comment: If I can convert it to an array (like in my example) there is no problem .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to establish correspondence between the string keys of `words` and the strings in each element of `sentences`. Repeat this process for all elements in `sentences` for the final result. Thus, we would have just one level of looping to solve it. The implementation would look like this -

```
K = words.keys()
sortidx = np.argsort(K)
V = np.vstack(words.values())[sortidx]
out = [V[np.searchsorted(K,S,sorter=sortidx)] for S in sentences]
```

Sample run -

```
In [122]: words
Out[122]: 
{'a': array([ 1.78505888, -0.40040435, -0.2555062 ]),
 'b': array([ 1.17213122,  0.38232652, -0.78477569]),
 'c': array([ 0.58101204, -0.23254054, -0.5700197 ]),
 'd': array([-0.07545012, -0.10094538, -0.98136142])}

In [123]: sentences
Out[123]: [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'd'], ['d', 'c']]

In [124]: K = words.keys()
     ...: sortidx = np.argsort(K)
     ...: V = np.vstack(words.values())[sortidx]
     ...: out = [V[np.searchsorted(K,S,sorter=sortidx)] for S in sentences]
     ...: 

In [125]: out
Out[125]: 
[array([[ 1.78505888, -0.40040435, -0.2555062 ],
        [ 0.58101204, -0.23254054, -0.5700197 ]]),
 array([[ 1.17213122,  0.38232652, -0.78477569],
        [ 1.78505888, -0.40040435, -0.2555062 ],
        [-0.07545012, -0.10094538, -0.98136142]]),
 array([[-0.07545012, -0.10094538, -0.98136142],
        [ 0.58101204, -0.23254054, -0.5700197 ]])]
```

Comment: My dictionary will be very big, so I don't think it's a good idea to duplicate it.

Comment: @dooms Duplicate what exactly? Could you clarify?

Comment: Here 'V' and 'K' are created from 'words' so basically you're splitting my dictionary into keys and values. So in memory there will be twice the size of words.

Comment: @dooms Well I am not sure about the memory requirements here, but logically I would think that since `words` store both keys and values. So, after extraction, the combined memory requirement for `V` and `K` would be similar to `words`. I would advise actually testing it out before making any calls.

Comment: It's not really an extraction, they are still there. After the call to keys() if you try words['a'] it should work.

Comment: @dooms That's right. We are not clearing out `words`, so it's still there. We are not doing "in-place" use of it.